# 500 internal server error when using flask

Tags: python, html, machine-learning, flask, keras

I'm deploying a model for first time using flask. I was following the tutorial from : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deploy-machine-learning-model-using-flask/
Also I can't make sense of how the script.py will be able to call index.html
Here is my script.py file:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template("index.html")
def ValuePredictor(to_predict_list): 
    to_predict = np.array(to_predict_list).reshape(1, 8) 
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl", "rb")) 
    result = loaded_model.predict(to_predict) 
    return result[0] 
  
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST']) 
def result(): 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        to_predict_list = request.form.to_dict() 
        to_predict_list = list(to_predict_list.values()) 
        to_predict_list = list(map(int, to_predict_list)) 
        result = ValuePredictor(to_predict_list)         
        if int(result)== 1: 
            prediction ='Chance of diabetes'
        else: 
            prediction ='You are safe'            
        return render_template("result.html", prediction = prediction)
```

Here is the index.html file:

```
<html> 
<body> 
    <h3>Diabetes Prediction</h3> 
  
<div> 
  <form action="/result" method="POST"> 
    <label for="age">Age</label> 
    <input type="text" id="age" name="age"> 
    <br> 
    <label for="preg">Number of times pregnant </label>
    <input type="text" id="preg" name="preg"> 
    <br> 
    <label for="p_glu">Plasma glucose concentration a 2 hours in an oral glucose tolerance test </label> 
    <input type="text" id="p_glu" name="p_glu"> 
    <br> 
    <label for="bp">Diastolic blood pressure (mm Hg) </label> 
    <input type="text" id="bp" name="bp"> 
    <br> 
    <label for="thickness">Triceps skin fold thickness (mm)</label> 
    <input type="text" id="thickness" name="thickness"> 
    <br> 
    <label for="insulin">2-Hour serum insulin (mu U/ml)</label> 
    <input type="text" id="insulin" name="insulin"> 
    <br>
    <label for="bmi">Body mass index (weight in kg/(height in m)^2)</label> 
    <input type="text" id="bmi" name="bmi"> 
    <br> 
    <label for="diab">Diabetes pedigree function</label> 
    <input type="text" id="diab" name="diab"> 
    <br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
  </form> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

The result.html file is:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
   <body> 
       <h1> {{ prediction }}</h1> 
   </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error, look in the web server error log.

Comment: Also, I notice that you're referring to lots of variables and functions such as `render_template()`, `request`, and `np`, but you haven't imported them anywhere.

Comment: @JohnGordon It's me trying it for first time, it'd be kind of you to pinpoint the error and suggest the edit!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use uninmported functions.

You need to add at the start of your python script:

from flask import request, render_template

Comment: It solved the first issue, now I'm able to input the info, but now the same error is in result.html .